# Compiler can't resolve generic types?

Tags: c#, generics

Is there any difference between:

```
public interface IPathfinding<T> where T : IPathfindingEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetShortestPath(IPathfindingUtils<IGraphNode<T>> utils);
}
```

and:

```
public interface IPathfinding<T> where T : IPathfindingEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetShortestPath(IPathfindingUtils<IGraphNode<IPathfindingEntity>> utils);
}
```

I'm scratching my head as intuitively it doesn't seem like there should be yet I am receiving compiler error in example #1:

`IGraphNode<T> cannot be used as parameter T in the generic type IPathfindingUtils<T>. There is no implicit reference conversion from IGraphNode<T> to IGraphNode<IPathfindingEntity>`

I haven't changed the definition of `IGraphNode<T>` or `IPathfindingUtils<T>` between trying to compile the 2 examples, here are the definitions for those interfaces:

```
public interface IPathfindingUtils<T> where T : IGraphNode<IPathfindingEntity>
{
    float Heuristic(T from, T to);
    IEnumerable<T> CreatePath(T from);
}

public interface IGraphNode<T> : INode<T>, IComparable<IGraphNode<T>> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    IList<float> Costs { get; }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to read about covariance and contravariance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your former examples and the latter examples are different. In former you are using T as passed type while in latter T is only Template and is not known. I hope , I could explain.

Comment: Please see my answer below and let me know if I've answered my own question?

Answer (score 0):

IGraphNode requires T to be an IComparable.

So you will want your code to be the following:

```
 public interface IPathfinding<T> where T : IPathfindingEntity, IComparable
 {
     IEnumerable<T> GetShortestPath(IPathfindingUtils<IGraphNode<T>> utils);
 }
```

Comment: It is IComparable<IGraphNode<T>> which is just a derivation of IComparable right?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I've rubber ducked myself and realized what the problem is.

For posterity:

In example #1, the constraint on `T` is `IPathfindingEntity`. `IGraphNode<T>` is not constrained against `IPathfindingEntity` and so `IPathfindingUtils<IGraphNode<T>> utils` is not valid since `T` in this case is `IPathfindingEntity` and that would break liskov substitution against `IGraphNode<T>` constraint which is not fullfilled!

So solution is to just make IPathfinding specifiy IGraphNode constraint in method definition as per example #2?